# Adding Subpage to Google Search Console (Things to be careful)

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search, search-results

I have 4 versions `(http/https)` x `(www/non www)` of my website in search console.

But I realised that I needed search analytics information on a subpage's ranking on google, but when I check search analytics, I didn't have this information for my subpage.

So I have added this subpage (`https://www.example.com/mypage`) as a new site.

> Q1: Is there any negative affects of this action ?
>
> Q2: Is that a rational action ? I mean, am I on the right track for my goal?
>
> Q3: Is there anything I should do more? (Like adding 4 versions of this subpage, or adding a sitemap, or any other thing that I can't think of.)

Comment: Do you really need 4 versions? If they all present the exact same content in the same language, then only one version will be indexed in search engines if any at all.

Comment: @Mike: No, you only need the canonical version.  But there are some cases when having all versions is beneficial, most often when someone changes from http to https or wants to set the preferred address.

Comment: You can't add a URL other than the home page as a site under Google Search Console since it only supports domain level sites. But, Google can establish the home URL but that is done outside of Google Search Console. It is no problem having 4 variations assuming that they are unique or you are using canonical links or redirections, otherwise your going to run into trouble with duplicate content.

Comment: @SimonHayter You can [add your site section/sub directory as well into search console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en) like http://www.example.com/foo/

Comment: @Goyllo... yes, but the/she would then be advised to have over 20 variations, not 4. Since each folder = 4 variations, 4 folders = 16, plus the base domain without folder is another 4. Unless they use a different content management system for each folder, I don't see the reason for it. Analytics, maybe, Search Console, no, because your only making it more complex and time consuming when all of it can be done under 1 variation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check final page ranking (like `www.example.com/this-is-my-final-page-and-there-is-no-any-subdirectory-after-that/`) you can use search analytics reports without adding new property into search console. To do that click on pages option and add your final URL like this.

[image: Analytic subpage on Google search console]

If you want analytics reports at section level like `www.example.com/sub-directory/` then you can create a new property into search console and add canonical version of website, for example if you open `www.example.com/sub-directory/` in browser and it's redirect to `https://www.example.com/sub-directory/` then add only https version properly, there is no need to add all variants in most cases (Check oskar Skog comment). Now let's comes to your questions.

1. If you've parent property `www.example.com` as well sub directory `www.example.com/section/` then you'll not going to get reports on both properly, here [parent property will win here according to this doc.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en) So add sub section properly only if you've very big site and want search analytics report at specific section.
2. I will add multiple section property into search console only, if my website is very large and I have really big section on my site, like `www.example.com/tutorial/` and `www.example.com/news/` etc. otherwise to track final URL, just check my first screenshot.
3. You only require canonical version property, other variants(at section level) will be empty and will not going to show any reports.  **Remember:** Google will show search analytics report only for indexed pages, and Google index only your canonical version of URL, not all variants with http/https,www/non-www.

Comment: I filtered the search console by page name and It shows my position wrong. I have been at the second page for 2 months, but it says my position 36.7. (This misunderstanding made me think that, it is giving me information about my homepage, and adding subpage as new porperty and creating this question above )  A1: you said parent property "will win", but the document you mentioned doesn't say it will surprass, it just says that "parent will include data for the subpath as well". A2: I don't understand why there is a relation of correct data, and site's being large. A3: Okay.

Comment: @HOY ... but it says my position 36.7... This takes into account all searches where your site/page was returned within a SERP result set. Your own searches are just your own searches and does not take into account all the searches made by other search engine users.

Comment: 1. Search console display average position. Users from other country doesn't see your site in second page all the time. So It's average position and it is not real time. 2. The doc says if you add both property then parent will display data, it doesn't say both will display data and it make sense to me as well, but feel free to check yourself 3. When site is very large and it's divided into many portion then adding sub section is right choose, but if it is small, then it's time consuming process to check analytics data from diff property, but you can go ahead, I don't know your situation :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a little update here, because [Google has changed their policy](https://security.googleblog.com/2018/02/a-secure-web-is-here-to-stay.html) and in consequence only https page will be taking into account.